# TADOQuery / TADOConnection behavior on connection error : override default?

Tags: delphi, error-handling, connection, ado

I have an issue in a legacy Delphi application using ADO to connect to MS SQL server.

The app is polling the db every 1 minute for updates. If connection is lost, and the app is minimized to the tray, for a long time (e.g. 30 min), the window, when maximized again, contains many message dialogs saying "Connection error".

To change this behavior I first looked at some `try...except` block but found nothing. The source code doesn't contain the text "Connection error" either and no application-wide setting such as ApplicationEventsException ...

Seems like this behavior is set up at the application or the component level, but I haven't 
been able to find how.

I haven't had Delphi experience before so I don't have a clue. 
Does anyone know where to look for ?

Comment: Possibly the error message is coming from the MDAC layer.  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the OnInfoMessage of your TAdoConnection, to see if the event triggers when the connection is lost?  Also try looking at the connection's Errors collection.

Comment: @MartynA OnInfoMessage event has no handler. After inserting an empty handler and setting breakpoint on it it never fires. I also tried to set up `Application.OnException` event handler, but _before_ it fires I still get a dialog box saying "Connection error" or "Login failed for user X" in my tests.

Comment: Not sure I follow about "inserting an empty handler" - you have to put some code in it, otherwise it will simply be deleted when you save the unit and so will never be called.

Comment: @MartynA sorry, it isn't really empty, it contains a line that I could put a breakpoint on

Comment: Ok, I was just checking.  What Provider type is your TAdoConnection set to - Double-click it and follow "Use connection string .. Build" to find out?  Mine is set to "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" ...

Comment: Yes, Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

Comment: If I set my connection string to use a server that doesn't exist, when I set its Connected property to true, I get a pop-up message with a Red cross inside and the message "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied".  That pop-up is apparently generated by the MDAC layer.  If I set up a handler for Application.OnException, I can catch that error before it displays in the pop-up and do whatever I like with it.  I suggest you try doing similar as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not v. comfortable posting this as an answer, because I can't reproduce exactly the behaviour you report.)

If no code in your application is generating the pop-ups you describe, most likely they're coming from the MDAC layer.  The way to suppress them seems to be to set up a TApplication.OnException handler.  This is simple to do, as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := HandleException;
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleException(Sender : TObject;  E : Exception);
begin
  ShowMessage(E.Message);
end;
```

Obviously you wouldn't really want ShowMessage() in your handler because it would just move the problem, not cure it